# Send text messages with viber in Android application

Tags: android, message

I have written an Android application. I want to send a text message with [Viber](http://www.viber.com/)( if it is installed). Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can launch an intent to the Viber package with the text as extras in the bundle using the relevant keys.

**EDIT**

As an example, this will launch the Wireless Settings activity.

```
startActivity( new Intent( Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS ) );
```

If you choose an Action Viber supports (if any) then it should be launched.

Comment: Dear ScouseChris, thanks for your answer. Is there any source code available ?  (What are the relevant keys, here ? )

Answer (score 0):

this site provide Viber API.

test it.

http://viberapi.ir/